# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'print_item_cost'

Tags: python-3.x

While running this code I am receiving the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 33, in <module>
    item.print_item_cost()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'print_item_cost'
```

I have verified the attribute is defined in the object, so I am not clear why this error is being thrown.

```
class ItemToPurchase:
    def __init__(self, name = 'none', price = 0, qty = 0):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.qty = qty

    def print_item_cost(self):
        print('%s %d @ $%d = $%d' % (self.name, self.qty, self.price, (self.price * self.qty))) 

    def calculate_subtotal(self):
        return self.price * self.qty

if __name__ == "__main__":
    i = 0
    order_list = []
    for i in range(2):
        print('Item %d' % int(i + 1))
        print('Enter the item name:')
        input_name = input()
        item = input_name
        item = ItemToPurchase()
        item.name = input_name        
        print('Enter the item price:')
        item.price = int(input())
        print('Enter the item quantity:')
        item.qty = int(input())
        order_list.append(input_name)

    print('\nTOTAL COST')
    total = 0
    for item in order_list:
        print(item, '\n')
        item.print_item_cost()
        total += item.calculate_subtotal()
    print('\nTotal: $%d' % total)
```

The program input I am giving is:

```
Chocolate Chips
3
1
Bottled Water
1
10
```

Which should result in the following output:

```
Item 1
Enter the item name:
Enter the item price:
Enter the item quantity:

Item 2
Enter the item name:
Enter the item price:
Enter the item quantity:

TOTAL COST
Chocolate Chips 1 @ $3 = $3
Bottled Water 10 @ $1 = $10

Total: $13
```

Comment: try `order_list.append(item)`

Comment: @PRMoureu, I made the change you recommended and now the following is the output of the code: ```Item 1
Enter the item name:
Enter the item price:
Enter the item quantity:
Item 2
Enter the item name:
Enter the item price:
Enter the item quantity:

TOTAL COST
<__main__.ItemToPurchase object at 0x7f13f3fe4c18> 

Chocolate Chips 1 @ $3 = $3
<__main__.ItemToPurchase object at 0x7f13f3fe4cc0> 

Bottled Water 10 @ $1 = $10

Total: $13```

Comment: yes because you are using `print(item, '\n')`

Comment: Remove the `print(item` line

Comment: @PRMoureu that did the trick, thanks so much.  I put that print line in to help me debug the code.  I am not sure why that is causing the output.

Comment: this is the default representation of an object in python. You can also rename your method `print_item_cost` to `__repr__` and then you could just use `print(item)`

Comment: @PRMoureu ah got it.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're appending a string, not the item object to the list

```
input_name = input()
...
order_list.append(input_name)
```

Then looping over that list, expecting it not to be strings...

---

I'd recommend cleaning up that section a little so that you actually call the constructor of the class

```
    print('Enter the item name:')
    input_name = input()

    print('Enter the item price:')
    price = int(input())

    print('Enter the item quantity:')
    qty = int(input())

    order_list.append(ItemToPurchase(input_name, price, qty))
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the recommendation, I will make those changes.  Changing order_list.append(input_name) to order_list.append(item) and removing the print(item, '\n') did the trick.  I really appreciate the help.